# Sending forgot password emails

Tags: php, email, forgot-password

I am building a service that will have a 'forgot my password' feature.  In addition to that, it will also email users when results are ready from my service.

I would like to ensure delivery of my emails so I was looking around to find a service that would let me send emails.

All that I've been able to find so far are services that require a user to opt-in to a list.

In other words, I've been unable to find any that will let me send customized messages to individual users.

I am currently using swiftmailer for php but would really like to find a service to do this...Anyone know of one?

Edit1:  It's not that I don't like swiftmailer but more that I want to make sure I do not have my emails end up getting blocked by spam filters.  Also, it would be easier to rely on a service that already has the stuff setup that Atwood talked about in that article.

Comment: One other thing, and this may speak to the swiftmailer issue. Mr. Atwood commented on sending emails in a recent Coding Horror article well worth reading here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *very* low volume solution that I use, and by low volume, I mean under twenty pieces per day, is to setup a GMail account and send your messages from that account. There are plenty of very simple programmatic solutions for this. Just Google for "php gmail send" and take your pick!